# Подскажите, каким образом можно реализовать фильтр "closing" на JAI (Java Advanced Imaging)?

Tags: java, изображения

Как пример того что мне нужно: фильтр "opening" может быть реализован комбинируя фильтры "erode" и "dialate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел объяснения тут: [Описание фильтров OpenCV](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/opencv-image-processing-using-morphological-filters)

В соответствии со статьей:

> Фильтр "opening" - может быть выполнен последовательным применением
>   фильтра "erode" и "dilate".
>
> Фильтр "closing" - может быть выполнен последовательным применением
>   фильтра "dilate" и "erode" (обратная последовательность).